# Tutorials on Open Packaging Conventions / System.IO.Packaging

Tags: .net, system.io.packaging, open-packaging-convention

Has anyone seen a good tutorial on [Open Packaging Conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions) and the [System.IO.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) namespace?

I have some areas where I think this technology could be useful, but I'm nervous because I don't quite understand it and I'm stuck on some of the terminology.

Comment: System.IO.Packaging came with .NET 3. Just a note for people who stumble apon this thread and are stuck with .net 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eric White has a pretty good introduction here:

<s>http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/packages-and-parts.aspx</s>

http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/screen-cast-overview-of-the-open-packaging-conventions-part-1/

Comment: Thanks! Nut graf for me: "The Package itself contains a collection of relationships, and any individual PackagePart can also contain a collection of relationships. The main document body will be a part that is referred to by the PackageRelationshipCollection collection in the Package."

Comment: Also, I would add an MSDN article that I wrote entitled: Essentials of the Open Packaging Conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361919.aspx.   Also recorded two screen-casts: http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2012/05/10/screen-cast-overview-of-the-open-packaging-conventions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`System.IO.Packaging` namespace allows to access the package related info as Digital signature, Encryption, relations between the various xml files and package properties of that file.

It also allows to access the File as part, as a collection of Individual objects.